# Arranging numbers c# code

Tags: c#

Can someone help fix this code? It's supposed to arrange the numbers in order so from lowest to highest. However im having trouble running the code...it wont print anything either. thanks

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] IN_AR_Numbers = { 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7 };

        PrintArray(IN_AR_Numbers);
        BubbleSort(IN_AR_Numbers);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void BubbleSort(int[] IN_AR_NumbersSorted)
    {
        int IN_Temp = 0;
        bool BL_HasSwapped = false;
        int IN_Swapcount = 0;

        do
        {
            BL_HasSwapped = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < IN_AR_NumbersSorted.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j] > IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j + 1])
                {
                    IN_Temp = IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j + 1];
                    IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j + 1] = IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j];
                    IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j] = IN_Temp;
                    BL_HasSwapped = true;
                    IN_Swapcount++;
                }
            }
        }
        while (BL_HasSwapped);

        PrintArray(IN_AR_NumbersSorted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also add code for `PrintArray()` function

Comment: Is bubble sort your choice of algorithm for implementing sorting, or is someone making you use it?

Answer (score 2):

Your not writing anything out in the code given.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] IN_AR_Numbers = { 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7 };

        BubbleSort(IN_AR_Numbers);

        foreach (var i in IN_AR_Numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void BubbleSort(int[] IN_AR_NumbersSorted)
    {
        int IN_Temp = 0;
        bool BL_HasSwapped = false;
        int IN_Swapcount = 0;

        do
        {
            BL_HasSwapped = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < IN_AR_NumbersSorted.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j] > IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j + 1])
                {
                    IN_Temp = IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j + 1];
                    IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j + 1] = IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j];
                    IN_AR_NumbersSorted[j] = IN_Temp;
                    BL_HasSwapped = true;
                    IN_Swapcount++;
                }
            }
        }
        while (BL_HasSwapped);
    }   
}
```

Gives

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I removed the `PrintArray` function that isn't in the code as given and added a loop to write the array out:

```
foreach (var i in IN_AR_Numbers)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VzTGJw))